# How to speed up custom object comparator

Tags: java, android, performance, comparator

I am trying to sort a large arraylist of objects for my podcast app. This is a Wear OS app so most devices have much less memory and processing speed than a normal modern Android device. Loading episodes in the correct order isn't very noticeable in podcasts with a small amount, but ones with hundreds of episodes take up to 10 seconds to sort. How can I speed this up?

I thought about sorting the episodes and saving them in the correct order in my sqlite database, but all episodes are stored in their own table. I'm guessing I should have saved dates as milliseconds rather than a string. I imagine there would have been a smarter way to store them initially, but now they will just be in the order they were found in all the users databases.

What can I do to speed up this process? Should I just do this in the background?

```
public static Comparator<Episode> DateComparator = new Comparator<Episode>() {

    public int compare(Episode episode1, Episode episode2) {
        if (episode1 == null || episode1.getDate() == null) {
            if (episode2 == null || episode2.getDate() == null) {
                return 0;
            }
            return -1;
        } else if (episode2 == null || episode2.getDate() == null) {
            return 1;
        }

        Date date1 = episode1.getDate();
        Date date2 = episode2.getDate();

        return date2.compareTo(date1);
    }

};

public Date getDate() {
    if(this.date != null) {
        try {
            return fdf.parse(this.date);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private FastDateFormat fdf = FastDateFormat.getInstance("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
```

Comment: Not knowing which sort utility you are using, I'd guess that any given Episode will be visited (compared) more than once.  Assuming this I'd avoid re-parsing the date string on subsequent accesses by using an EpisodeWrapper class which saves the parsed date.  For more info I'd also add a "compare counter" for each episode to assess the efficiency of the sort.  Note also your compare function invokes 'getDate' 2 times for each episode per compare so that can be optimized even without the wrapper.

Comment: Also, it is hard to tell from listing but the the FastDateFormat can be made static - if it's a member of the Episode class (couldn't tell) then it is being created on each instantiation of a Episode, which will save n-1 calls to FastDateFormat.getInstance().

Comment: Okay. I followed those suggestions. Making the FastDateFormat object static and storing the date in an object cut the initial loading time in half. Storing the date makes loading time almost immediate after the date object is loaded, so I guess most of the work is done parsing the date. Would it be faster to parse the date myself by parsing the string or storing some different value in the database? Loading time is still about 5 seconds for a large podcast.

Comment: It's unlikely your parsing would be better unless you could optimize based on your knowledge of the data.  Best approach is to avoid repeated parsing.  If you could store the date.time() value in the DB that would benefit subsequent sorts at the cost of the update.  Did you also eliminate the 2 calls to getDate() for each episode per compare?

Comment: Okay. Saving as time instead of saving the string date seems to be the best solution. Rather than updating the database, I just parse the long into a string and saved it in the same column, then try parsing a long before using the FastDateFormat. If that fails, I then use the FastDateFormat. This way the date parse only has to be done once. Loading time only takes a little over a second now for hundreds of episodes. Do you want to post this as the answer, or should I answer it with the updated code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoiding repeated parsing of date/time strings is the general theme of this collection of simple improvements:

- Create a wrapper class to save the parsed date-time value since each Episode is likely to be visited (compared) multiple times during a sort.
- Make the FastDateFormat.getInstance static so it's invoked only once.
- Update the DB with the date-time value (long) for subsequent accesses.
- Eliminate the multiple invocations of getDate() for each Episode per compare.

Comment: Yep something like that.